# How to change the background colour of the code-runner output in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I want to change the background colour of the output given by the 'code-runner' extension in Visual Studio Code by using the appropriate keyword in the setting.json file.

This is the area where I want the colour to be changed:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwhCK.png)

Comment: change a different theme, or customize the `terminal background color`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just find a theme that suits your desire.

To get a specific background colour though:

1. Open your settings.json file (type settings into command palette and click on "Settings: Open Preferences (JSON)"
2. Add the following:

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "editor.background": "#<your colour here>"
 }
```

Voila, new colour. You can change many of the other colours through a similar process, just type a new line with `editor.` and you'll see the options pop up.